# Priority Queue with asynchronous bubbling up/down across multiple threads; how can I make the conflict resolution work properly?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, priority-queue

In summary, I have a (binary tree) priority queue that will be be accessed by multiple threads (popping the head/bubbling the head node down, incrementing specific node priority and bubbling that node up).  The challenge that arises is when a bubble-down hits a bubble-up or two bubble-ups hit each other.

Now, I want the bubbling to take place unhindered when there is no conflict, ideally only forcing synchronous execution when conflict arises.  To that end, I thought that I could have a mutex for each node, and lock_guard the mutexes for relevant nodes in the bubbling function.

The priority_queue itself works properly and to my satisfaction.  Ideally I wouldn't need to do much major reworking in order to make it work with multiple threads.

The first thing I tried was something like

```
class ReadQueue
{
private:
    std::vector<int> pq_lookup;
    std::vector<uint32_t> priority_queue;
    std::vector<std::mutex> pq_mutex;

public:
    void Initialize(
        _In_ int read_unit_count)
    {
        this->pq_lookup.resize(read_unit_count, 0);
        this->priority_queue.resize(read_unit_count, 0);
        this->pq_mutex.resize(read_unit_count);
```

...

which, of course, failed.  As I understand it, this relates to the lack of a mutex copy constructor and totally fubars any attempt to resize a vector of mutexes.

The second thing I tried was to replace

```
std::vector<std::mutex> pq_mutex

...

   this->pq_mutex.resize(read_unit_count);
```

with

```
std::mutex* pq_mutex

...

   this->pq_mutex = malloc(sizeof(std::mutex) * read_unit_count);
```

This didn't work either, as the moment I tried to do a lock_guard on a mutex, I get an access violation.  Of course, duh, I just allocated memory, I didn't actually initialize any class mutex, whoops.

Now, in the greater context of what I'm doing, read_unit_count is constant as soon it can be, but is and needs to be assigned during runtime, thus the resizing during initialization.

How can I make the mutexes work the way I want them to?  Failing that, any other relevant suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried using, instead of mutexes, a vector of atomic values?

Comment: Or, since vector requires that the class be moveable or copy-constructable, you can use a deque or list.

Comment: I may try a deque or a list then.  However, my understanding of atomic values is shaky.  If I were to have two child nodes with the same parent in the bubbling up process simultaneously, could atomic values guarantee that the bubbling would complete on one of them before the next one would get underway?  What's the scope of the locking that takes place with them?

Comment: Atomic guaruantees only that R/W operations to be done by a single thread at the same time, and they need no locking. After a second read, I noticed that you need some processing besides R/W operations to the values, so atomic will not solve your needs.

Comment: Please note that with deques, `insert`s and `push_(back|front)` will fail to compile. You should use either `resize` or `emplace(|_back|_front)`.

Comment: Before you spend any more time on this, you probably should profile your code to see if a simple mutex on the entire heap structure really causes a performance problem. If you decide you really need a lock-free priority queue, then build it with a skip list rather than a binary heap. See http://www.non-blocking.com/download/SunT03_PQueue_TR.pdf for a detailed example.